# Find the number of 4 digit numbers of the form $abcd$ such that $ab+cd$ is even

Tags: combinatorics

Let $n$ denote the number of 4 digit numbers of the form $abcd$ such that $ab+cd$ is even. Find the last digit of $n$.

There are two cases.

- $ab,cd$ is odd. Which means $a,b,c,d \in \text{odd}$. Number of such cases is $5!=120$
- $ab,cd$ is even. Atleast one of $\{a,b\}$ and atleast one of $\{c,d\}$ is even.

If $a$ is even, $a\in\{2,4,6,8\}$. If $b$ is even $b\in\{0,2,4,6,8\}$. In both cases atleast one of $c,d$ has to be even. Number of ways is $\binom{2}{1}\binom{5}{1}\binom{10}{1}$.

If $a$ is even, number of ways is $\binom{4}{1}\binom{10}{1}\cdot\binom{2}{1}\binom{5}{1}\binom{10}{1}$.

If $b$ is even, number of ways is $\binom{9}{1}\binom{5}{1}\cdot\binom{2}{1}\binom{5}{1}\binom{10}{1}$.

I am getting $0$ as the last digit of $n$. Answer given is $1$.

Comment: You seem to be assuming that the digits are different, but you never require that.

Comment: In addition to the comment above, even if the digits **ARE** different, you're still double counting the second case (i.e., you're double counting the case of both $a$ and $b$ even). You should use inclusion/exclusion.